# What are the methods to quantify the bacterial adhesion rate for the biofilms grown on coupons in CDC or annular bioreactor, non-invasively?

Tags: bacteriology

I'm interested to know that if I grow the biofilm on coupons in the CDC bioreactor at a particular shear stress, and after say 48 hours, I take out the coupon from the bioreactor to quantify the bacteria attached to it; what are the commonly preferred 'non-invasive' methods that I can use to do so? Can LIVE/DEAD staining be used in this case?
Additionally, if I want to know the bacterial adhesion rate (when the coupon is still inside the CDC bioreactor, and the baffle plate is rotating at say 80 rpm) at different time intervals (say after 1 hour, 4 hours, 8 hours), without disturbing the coupons, can I do that by using any Imaging technique?
Please let me know. Thank you for reading my question.
Regards,
Grishma

Comment: By "non-invasive", do you mean you want to quantify the bacteria in the biofilm in such a way that it can be re-insterted into the bioreactor and continue growing? What exactly are you to accomplish with this experimental design?

Comment: Thank you for your response. By non-invasive I mean to imply that can taking the images (without taking the coupons out of the bioreactor) at different time instances be possible. By knowing the growth at different time instances, I'm working towards figuring out the optimum time instance when we can introduce the disinfectant treatments.